# Unable to tree shake React and dependencies if they are not being used

Tags: webpack, tree-shaking

I am having trouble dead code eliminating unused React components.

I have created a sample project here - https://github.com/amithgeorge/webpack-issue-demo-1 ...

Three classes are defined,

- `class A` is a react component using prop-types,
- `class B` is a react component connected to redux using `connect HOC`,
- `class C` is a simple class and not a react component -

Code - https://github.com/amithgeorge/webpack-issue-demo-1/blob/5643302db776263db857259cc00c2bafe46acb8c/src/classes.js ....

In the entry file, I am only importing class C and using it - https://github.com/amithgeorge/webpack-issue-demo-1/blob/5643302db776263db857259cc00c2bafe46acb8c/src/index.js

I expected the output file to only contain class C, but it has everything!

https://github.com/amithgeorge/webpack-issue-demo-1/blob/5643302db776263db857259cc00c2bafe46acb8c/dist/main.js

If I remove the `propTypes` and remove the `connect`, then the code for ClassA and ClassB are not present. But the output still has the entire code of React, PropTypes and React-Redux. If these aren't being used, how do I get webpack to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding - Tree Shaking only works for ES2015 module and **Not for CommonJS module**.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

[image]

To test this, I have created a [repo here](https://github.com/raviroshan/webpack-tree-shaking-demo) and file1.js that has class `MyClass`.

Now, if you try exporting that as ESM and don't use inside `index.js` - It will **NOT** be part of your bundle.

But if you export it as CommonJS `module.exports = MyClass` and don't use - It will still be part of your bundle.

Same concept applies for Node_Modules also.

CommonJS modules

1. [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/axios.js)
2. [reactjs](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/index.js)

ESM modules

1. [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es)

If you just import `axios` and don't use it - It will still be part of bundle but un-used `lodash-es` will be not be.

Comment: Thank you for attempting this. But this is not a valid solution. If you check the final bundle, ie `main.js` it doesn't have the code for `Class C`. Webpack removed EVERYTHING. It only left behind the runtime code needed for webpack.

Comment: did you get a chance to go through it again?

Comment: @AmithGeorge: Got it, give me 30 minutes, will be posting a new Answer.

Comment: @AmithGeorge: Updated this answer with new findings.
Please validate at your end.